# How to pass array of object to select options in Vue 2.0

Tags: javascript, select, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a **select** which I want to populate from the array of objects like

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "Some name"},
 ... 
{"id": 5, "name": "Another name"}]
```

which is stored in **items** in data property of the Vue

```
var app = new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {
    items: [],
....

    }
})
```

I'm trying to do it like with the **v-for** and **v-model** like that:

```
  <select id="categories" v-model="items">
      <option v-for="item in items" :value="item.id">{{ item.name }}</option>
  </select>
```

and it doesn't work, however if I tried the same code with the int Array everything is fine. 
Can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **Use `v-model` for the selected value**

```
<select id="categories" v-model="selectedValue">
  <option v-for="item in items" :value="item.id">{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Add `selectedValue` to your data.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [],
    selectedValue: null

  }
})
```

```js
const items = [{"id": 1, "name": "Some name"},
{"id": 5, "name": "Another name"}]

var app = new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {
    items,
    selectedValue: null
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select id="categories" v-model="selectedValue">
      <option v-for="item in items" :value="item.id">{{ item.name }}</option>
  </select>
  
  Selected Value: {{selectedValue}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I can see that it's working well in the snippet however it doesn't in my code/page/. Even binding from select to selectedValue and next displaying.

selectedValue is still null.

Guess I have some kind of mistake somewhere.

Comment: @virtual98 If you want to post more code, or make a fiddle/codepen that shows your code breaking, I can take a look. Possibly you are setting `items` dynamically and setting it incorrectly?

Comment: Thanks again. 
This is the fiddle where I tried to show the process how I do it. 
https://jsfiddle.net/or0ppeu2/4/
Basically I have a tab clicking on which user triggered the request to API ( in the case of fiddle I emulated it by array) an then populates items array in data property on the Vue object. 
Strangely enough but everything is working fine in this fiddle )). 
Checked app.items in console and it seems that it's successfully populated with data from the request to API.

Comment: @virtual98 can you post the code thats not working to a gist?

Comment: @virtual98 Not sure if it makes a difference, but in the code where you say it works (getting items) you set items = response.data.data. In requestCategories you set categories = response.data.

Comment: Yeah it's equal response.data because API returns array (not a valid JSON like {"data":[],}. So there is no another inner layer in it. 
However when I write: 
<p v-for="cat in categories">{{ cat }}</p>
it's working fine and displays all the records from the request.

Comment: @virtual98 I can't see a reason why it wouldn't work. You do have a weird thing where you set `var app = new Vue(...)` and then you re-define `app` in your request functions, but I expect the local `app` would override the other higher level `app` and in any case, they would be the same object, But other than that, it looks like it should work.

Comment: @ Bert 
Ok, thanks! Will try to dig further. 
I've used `var app = this` in functions because otherwise I can't access global data variables in order to change something in them (when I tried just `this.variable`.  Don't know why it's so, but apparently this how it works (at least for now)